# Can you make the DateAdd interval vary based on value of the item you are adding to?

Tags: t-sql

I have following element on a sql query

```
datediff(d, dateadd(day, -14 - thing.daystoadd, getdate()), thing.EndTime) as DateExpDiff
```

Can I make the -14 vary based on thing.EndTime?

For instance if one row of thing.EndTime<'3/15/2013' I want it to be -14 but if its > 3/15/2013 I want it to be -10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `CASE` statement should work:

```
datediff(d, dateadd(day, CASE WHEN thing.EndTime<'3/15/2013' THEN -14 ELSE -10 END - thing.daystoadd, getdate()), thing.EndTime) as DateExpDiff
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you I didn't realize you could call a case in the parameters. Cool.